# How to turn an number into a roman numeral?

Tags: java

For a class we are creating a program that takes in a number and spits it out as a roman numeral. This should be really simple, because we don't even have to worry about four being IV. In this program four would be IIII. Anyone have any suggestions on how to do this...? We can't use array's. His instructions state:

This method prints, to the standard output and in purely additive
    * notation, the Roman numeral corresponding to a natural number.
    * If the input value is 0, nothing is printed.

I've tried it a couple different ways, and my logic just isn't right. I would really appreciate any suggestions you may have.

Here is what I last tried...

```
romanDigitChar(val);

 if (val - 1000 >= 0)
 {
    int thousands = val / 1000;
    int m_printed = 0;
       while ( m_printed < thousands )
       {
           System.out.print(romanDigitChar(1000));
           m_printed++;
       }
 }

if(val % 100 == 0 && (val/100) >= 5)
{
    System.out.print(romanDigitChar(500));
}
if(val % 100 == 0 && (val/100) < 5)
{
   int hundreds = val / 100;
    int C_printed = 0;
    {
       while ( C_printed < hundreds )
       {
           System.out.print(romanDigitChar(100));
           C_printed++;
       }
    }   
}
if(val % ROMAN_L == 0)
{
    System.out.print(romanDigitChar(50));
}
if(val % 10 == 0 && (val/10) < 5)
{
   int tens = val / 10;
    int X_printed = 0;
    {
       while ( X_printed < tens )
       {
           System.out.print(romanDigitChar(10));
           X_printed++;
       }
    }   
}
if(val % 5 == 0)
{
    System.out.print(romanDigitChar(50));
}
if(val == 0)
System.out.println("Zero");
```

Comment: What's working? What's not working? What are your test cases?

Comment: Of course, part of the challenge is figuring out which Roman numeral standard to adhere to.  There are several, with major disagreements.

Comment: Are these WiFi roaming numerals? Or Bluetooth?

Answer (score 0):

I am unsure exactly what you mean but

```
public String createRomanNumeral(int romanNumeral){
   String romanNumeralString = "";
   for(int x=0;x<romanNumeral;x++){
       romanNumeralString += "I";
   }
   return romanNumeralString;
}
```

will work if my guess is correct.

Comment: Wow, that's a lot of I's.

Comment: Oh, sorry I didn't see that no array thing :(  edit: I changed it to not use arrays :)

Comment: There are now two variables called `romanNumeral`.

Comment: @john01dav, please, use StringBuilder